# Извлечь из веб-страницы данные о зарплате

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ребята помогите как вынуть через регулярку - все .. до следующей <br> ??

```
$tmp["description"] = "<![CDATA[<b>Зарплата:</b> от 17 000 руб.<br/><br/><b>Город:</b>";
$text=preg_replace("",$tmp["description"]);
```

Мне надо вынуть "Зарплата:</b> от 17 000 руб." то есть как я понимаю в начале надо указать: 1) все что написанно по русски 2) открывающего б 3) до <br/>

Полный пример:

```
<![CDATA[<b>Зарплата:</b>
                от 60 000 руб.<br/><br/>

                <b>Город:</b>
                Кузнецк<br/><br/>

                <b>Должностные обязанности:</b><br/>
                - Контроль и обеспечение приемки, выгрузки, складирования, отгрузки продукции, материалов и комплектующих<br />
- Обеспечение сохранности материальных ценностей<br />
- Работа по приему, хранению и отпуску товарно - материальных ценностей на складах, сохранности товарно-материальных ценностей<br/><br/>

                <b>Требования к квалификации:</b><br/>
                - Обязателен опыт работы в аналогичной должности<br />
- Уверенный пользователь ПК, 1С<br/><br/>

                <b>Компания:</b>
                «СГК-Трубопроводстрой-5»<br/><br/>

                <a target=_blank href="#">Просмотреть полный текст объявления о вакансии</a><br/><br/>]]>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам скорее лучше воспользоваться `preg_match`:

```
$tmp["description"] = "<![CDATA[<b>Зарплата:</b> от 17 000 руб.<br/><br/><b>Город:</b>";

preg_match("#b>(.*?)<br#is", $tmp["description"], $result);

var_dump($result[1]);
```

Comment: то же не так, несработало(

Comment: У меня всё ок: string(28) "Зарплата:</b> от 17 000 руб."

Comment: наверное баг из за того что я не все прислал, на вашем примере отрабатывает - но у меня строка большая - наверное в этом загвоздка .... что то наверное мешает в конце строки

Comment: @oldzas это как принести колесо автомобиля и спросить, почему машина не заводится :-)

Comment: согалсен, а куда деваться, учусь, ковыряю то тут то там..

Comment: Добавьте модификатор s, иначе регулярное выражение будет искать только в строке без переносов. Причем регулярное выражение выдаст только первое совпадение. Обновил пост.